# error : unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, testng

I've this code

[image]

When I execute this code in my IDE (eclipse). My browser open a window with google.

But if I execute this code in cmd or in Jenkins, I've this error :

```
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class demo.DemoJenkins - unable
to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

I followed this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e8I3A49ERc and I did everything like him, but when I would like to open a browser with this code with Jenkins or cmd. I've a error.

I use Selenium webdriver, TestNG, Java for writing code. if anyone can help me, thanks a lot !

Comment: Do not add code as a link to a screenshot. add it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add the `selenium-api.jar` to your classpath,

Comment: Ok but where i add this ? Because in Eclispe I don't have any problem. I can add selenium -api.jar in Eclipse but it change nothing. My problem come from cmd and Jenkins. If it works in cmd, it works in Jenkins.

Comment: @Fikcam How do you run the program

Comment: I run the program with cmd

Comment: Java -jar your_porg?

Comment: It does'nt work : "aucun attribut manifest principal dans selenium-api.jar" (sorry my PC is in french)

Comment: I use selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

Comment: ok bro u are the best ! You have help me with "add the ..... to your classpath". It's not selenium-api.jar but selenium-<version>.jar. Before I try in cmd "set classpath=C:\...\Workspace\nameofproject\bin;C:\...\Workspace\nameofproject\libs\*;" And now I try with "C:\...\Workspace\nameofproject\selenium-server-standalone.jar" at the end and it works ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your test via Jenkins?

Try to create a maven project and run it via it. It will be easier to maintain and use if you want to use your project longer.